# ms Graph API Update tablerow fail for 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get an Excel online row via graph api but the call fails for 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url

I don't know what I am doing wrong please help

I tried V1.0 and beta with the same result

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mysite/drives/mydrive/workbook/worksheets('%7B my worksheet id %7D')/tables('%7B my table id %7D')/rows/1 | Error Message: The API you are trying to use could not be found. It may be available in a newer version of Excel.

Comment: Please share the requestid and timestamp for this failed request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, there is no such API endpoint that can pull a row directly. But Microsoft provides you a way to get that data. You can use the query parameters $top and $skip to pull any row as shown below.

I am trying to get the 4th record in my list

[image]

Now I will use the `Top` and `Skip` query parameters in my query as below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{Driveid}/Items/{Itemid}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/tables/Table1/rows?$top=1&$skip=3
```

You can see that I was able to pull the 4th record by giving the skip value 3 in it. So you need to keep $Top as 1 to pull one record and $skip value will vary with the `RequiredRow - 1`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Shiva, your answer works, and it turn out the MS convert that to /rows/itemAt(index=1)